# How can I make use of @Autowired and @Value annotations independent of Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

I have some code written for a Spring Boot application that I now want to reuse outside of Spring Boot (for standalone command line tools).

What is the shortest path from having a `PropertyResolver` and an annotated class that wants `@Value`s injected to an autowired bean instance?

For example, if I have a constructor

```
 @Autowired
 public TheBean(@Value("${x}") int a, @Value("${b}") String b){}
```

and I already set up (dynamically, in code)

```
 PropertyResolver props;
```

how can I make use of all this annotations so that I don't have to write the very explicit and repetitive

```
TheBean bean = new TheBean(
     props.getProperty("x", Integer.TYPE), 
     props.getProperty("y"));
```

I have the complete Spring Boot application (including Spring dependencies) on the classpath, but Spring has not been initialized (no call to `SpringApplication#run`, because that would bring up the whole web server application).

Comment: Create another, lighter Spring Configuration that only has the PropertyResolver as a bean, as well as your own beans?

Comment: Sounds like a plan. But how?

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate configuration, that only has the beans you want:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.myco.mypackage")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

And then instantiate a Spring context and get the bean from it as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-instantiating-container):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    TheBean myService = ctx.getBean(TheBean.class);
    myService.doStuff();
}
```